# Utility for search inside textfiles where results are directly editable

Tags: text-editor, text-search

Does a utility exist for searching in text files where search results are directly editable?

I don't want "Search and Replace" utility, but instead I want a "Search and Edit" utility where I can make manual changes in list of results and that changes will be automatically projected to appropriate text files without need to manually open/change/save those files.

EDIT: Ideally, a utility for Windows or Linux (Xubuntu).

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: Not exactly what you need but close (and effective) i believe. With Notepad++ you can search files in directories or or open documents. Results will be shown in a window below editor. Then you can double click a search row which opens original file in editor. So you dont need to find the file and location manually.

Comment: @ouzture: Yes, that's what I'm doing now. But perpetually alternate between keyboard and mouse is not as fluid as using the keyboard alone. After lot of googling it looks like application i am wanting does not exists yet!

Comment: If problem is just not using mouse, you can use shortcuts F4 and Shift+ F4. Just tried and it moves to next found result in the search results window even if in another file.

Comment: How are you searching a directory tree in NP++? Which menu item? Thanks in advance